# Is there a way to boot from ISO file in rEFInd Boot Manager?

Tags: boot, iso-image, refind

I am wonder if there is such feature in rEFInd - to run ISO file located on the USB stick. I can not use any superuser utilities such as dd to write an ISO directly. I can only repack it.

Comment: You can't boot from an ISO directly, you need to mount it first; or burn the contents to CD/USB stick.

Comment: Maybe i can mount it from efi-shell in refind?